# Round edges on a cylinder (Jelly shape)

Tags: edges

I am a beginner on blender. I followed the donut tutorial and then I'd like to make my own 3D object.

I am trying to make this :

[image]

I started by doing a cylinder and scaling 1/2 verteces in edit mode, so I have this :

[image]

I'd like to round corners but I don't know how to do it. I've tried to select each vertex and use Ctrl+Shit+B but it looks like this :

[image: strong text]

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your beveling the vertices, not the edges, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and in the *Operator* box make sure that the *Edge* option is selected.

To do the whole thing: Select the edge ring with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Left click, then go into the *Select* panel > *Checker Deselect*, it will select one edge out of 2 by default:

[image]

Scale up the selection with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>:

[image]

Bevel these edges with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

Bevel the top and bottom edges:

[image]

Scale the top, then back in *Object* mode, right click and Shade Smooth:

[image]